# HTML Scope Attribute - WCAG 2.0 G196

Tags: html, scope, wcag

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H63

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_scope.asp

In here it basically says for the standard, "include a scope for each row and/or column".

Now, if I have search results page with 400 results, and I display 10 at a time, would the second page's scope attribute start at 11, or begin again at 1?

Comment: The W3C document says: “Note: For simple tables that have the headers in the first row or column then it is sufficient to simply use the TH elements without scope.” This applies to most well-designed data tables.

Answer (score 4):

Neither. The possible values are `row`, `col`, `rowgroup` and `colgroup`, not 1, 2, 3, 4